# Xcode error: Cannot use instance member 'selectedWateredDate' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, self, dateinterval

I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting the following error using SwiftUI:

> Cannot use instance member 'selectedWateredDate' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

for my "dateInterval" variable.

```
@State private var selectedWateredDate = Date()
@State private var waterMeAgainIn: Date = Date().addingTimeInterval(7 * 86400)


let dateInterval = DateInterval(start: selectedWateredDate, end: waterMeAgainIn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the let property to a computed variable.

```
var dateInterval : DateInterval { DateInterval(start: selectedWateredDate, end: waterMeAgainIn)}
```

Comment: @izzieyo20 Not related to your question but note that not every day has 24 hours. If you need to add a week to a date you should use Calendar method `func date(byAdding component: Calendar.Component, value: Int, to date: Date, wrappingComponents: Bool = false) -> Date?` in your case `Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: Date())`

Comment: @izzieyo20 if I answered your question can you please mark it as an answer with the green check mark above.

Comment: Thanks, friends! Got a lot to learn. Dates are hard...